# Cannot insert Slovenian letter into a database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, collation

I'm having a problem with entering Slovenian characters such as "ć, č, đ, š".

This has never happened before, but now when I want to enter these values into a table column, I get an error:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x87' for column 'body' at row 1
```

I tried everything, changing database collation, table, column collation, everything, but it just won't go away.

Can you please help me?

This is mysql query I'm trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO  `twoofus`.`messages` (
`messageID` ,
`head` ,
`body` ,
`messageIP` ,
`userID`
)
VALUES (
'4234',  '4234',  '424',  'ćććć',  '2'
```

Comment: Please post your table definition to show us which character encoding settings you're currently using and how your `INSERT`-statement looks like.

Comment: Is it working if you choose text files in PHPMyAdmin. Via Google I found this problem [in console](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30131). What encoding is your browser using (maybe it mismatches and PHPMyAdmin does not change it?).

Comment: I'm sorry, Bjoern, how do I get my table definition?
I know it's InnoDB type.

Comment: I edited the question and added INSERT statement.

Comment: I'm guessing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc might be related.